# Font type with distinct weight

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need to add an external font type to my website. But I was only provided with the thin, bold and italic ttf files. Is it possible to change the font weight in css? Or I really have to have the other files with different weights?

Thank you very much!

Comment: For better results you should always have all the necessary native shapes otherwise you'll let the browser do sort of `faux` which will result in jaggy fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have the specified font-weight loaded, I believe it chooses the logically closest to it. Which would mean that you have to include different weights.

Answer (score 0):

There is a font-weight property in css, with values between 100-900. i.e:

```
font-weight: 700;
```

Comment: I tried that already, but the font-weight doesn't change. I have the ttf files for "thin", "italic" and "bold". So I wonder if I needthe other ttf files with different font-weight.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the one and only way to do it with css, if it's not working then I guess you have to get the other ttf files. I also have experiences of when font-weight isn't working, I suspect it only works with the basic font-families.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get the other files. Thank you very much!